# intercept calls to window and screen attributes from a firefox addon

Tags: javascript, window, firefox-addon, screen, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to intercept a sites calls to the window and screen objects from a firefox addon, for their width and height attributes and return my own values .

I have been trying to use an observer

```
const os = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);

os.addObserver({

    observe : function(subject, topic, data) {
        if (subject instanceof Ci.nsIDOMWindow && topic == 'content-document-global-created') {
            subject.wrappedJSObject.myfunction = function(){
                // Do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}, 'content-document-global-created', false);
```

This allows me to override normal javascript methods but I can't seem to change the screen or window attributes. Would a pagemod be able to modify it with a content script so the site will read the values specified in the addon?

Comment: Even if you specify `contentScriptWhen: 'start'` in your [pagemod constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod%28options%29), I believe that it still waits for the document to attach to the window before executing, so any changes made at that point could already be too late.

Comment: I don't get it. Intercept what kind of calls? So like whenever a website does `window.scrollTop = 454` or site does `window.resizeTo`?

Answer (score 0):

You would do it like this:

```
subject.wrappedJSObject.screen.__defineGetter__("width", function() { return myWidth });
```

I'm not sure on the timing as willma pointed out, but this is what the code looks like.